# 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, openweathermap

what am i doing wrong here?

I want to get weather focus for my City using OpenWeathermap API

I am getting this error:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

[image]

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public String WeatherDetail(string City)
{
    string appId = "*PUT MY API KEY HERE*";

    string url = string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={0}&units=metric&cnt=1&APPID={1}", City, appId);

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string json = client.DownloadString(url);
       
        RootObject weatherInfo = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<RootObject>(json);

        //Special VIEWMODEL design to send only required fields not all fields which    received from   
        //www.openweathermap.org api  

        ResultViewModel rslt = new ResultViewModel();

        rslt.Country = weatherInfo.sys.country;
        rslt.City = weatherInfo.name;
        rslt.Lat = Convert.ToString(weatherInfo.coord.lat);
        rslt.Lon = Convert.ToString(weatherInfo.coord.lon);
        rslt.Description = weatherInfo.weather[0].description;
        rslt.Humidity = Convert.ToString(weatherInfo.main.humidity);
        rslt.Temp = Convert.ToString(weatherInfo.main.temp);
        rslt.TempFeelsLike = Convert.ToString(weatherInfo.main.feels_like);
        rslt.TempMax = Convert.ToString(weatherInfo.main.temp_max);
        rslt.TempMin = Convert.ToString(weatherInfo.main.temp_min);
        rslt.WeatherIcon = weatherInfo.weather[0].icon;

        //Converting OBJECT to JSON String   
        var jsonstring = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rslt);

        //Return JSON string.  
        return jsonstring;

    }
```

Comment: Looks like a basic URL, what happens when you navigate to that URL in a browser or hit it with curl or something?

Also, are you sure its http and not https? I've not checked but had a quick look at their endpoint, looks to be https

Comment: HTTP 404 - means page is not found.  Check that the URL that you are expecting to go to is correct.  Just by looking at the URL I think it might be `https` rather than http.  Browsers tend to redirect you, but the code will not.

Comment: Thank you, i added https on the url it went through that line of code, however it is bring the same error here using    (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string json = client.DownloadString(url);

Comment: Also could this be because this is a FREE API subscription?